# Spark standalone master behind the vpn

Tags: apache-spark

I have a Spark standalone master running on a machine in the AWS VPC binding to the private IP address. I'm able to run spark jobs from the machine inside the VPC but not from my laptop that is connecting to the cluster via VPN. I checked executor logs on a spark worker and got `Cannot receive any reply in 120 seconds.`. Looks like networking issue.

Anybody knows how to solve that?

Comment: I already tried to set driver host by appending `--conf spark.driver.host=x.x.x.x` to spark-submit and disabling the firewall. Did not help.

Comment: If it's indeed a networking issue, I'd recommend starting with validating all the connectivity from the lowest layer to the highest. Check your security groups, network ACLs, VPN configuration (which depends on how you set it up) and routing tables. This might be more appropriate for ServerFault.